# Include urls for django-registration

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, django-registration

So i just installed django-registration and got the templates from https://github.com/macdhuibh/django-registration-templates

I'm getting a problem with the URL resolver, I get

> Reverse for 'auth_password_reset' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found.

as well as many others....

urls.py:

```
#Other stuff,

url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
```

Exactly as the docs specify.
Furthermore here's the html that throws the error. It's from login.html from the github. It's the one that threw this error but it seems i get something similar every time i try doing a reverse match on a url from the auth_url.py of django-registration.

```html
{% extends "main/header.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{ form.as_p }}

  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

<p>{% trans "Forgot password" %}? <a href="{% url 'auth_password_reset' %}">{% trans "Reset it" %}</a>!</p>
<p>{% trans "Not member" %}? <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">{% trans "Register" %}</a>!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what went wrong,
I added the URL pattern in the app's urls.py not the root project's one.

Hope this helps someone out too!